# Convert byte[] to Buffer type

Tags: java, android, arrays, buffer

I am working in Android. I need to convert byte[] to Buffer type. In Android, I have seen a type Buffered that I needed to use in particular functions. But, I my data source is type byte[].

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Take a look at [ByteBuffer.wrap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap%28byte%5b%5d%29):

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
Buffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
```

There's also a `ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[] array, int start, int byteCount)` if you only want to wrap part of an array.